# Php - Regex help, different scenario

Tags: php, regex

I am new to using regex.

I am currently using preg_replace and trying to match words, if same do something.

I am using `"/\b".$word."\b/"`.

The string is 'Hello world2017 is an example of hello world2017 project!"

3 things I need to fix 
- 'Hello' and 'hello' is not consider as 2.
- word with letter are not consider as 2.
- word with punctuation are ignore

I came across
\w can match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_")
\W can match a non-word character

What the correct combination to fix the 3 things and how to append with \b.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not consider as 2."?

Comment: Hi, I mean word count for similar word, in this case there 2 hello in the string.
"not consider as 2.", because of case sensitive 'H'ello. 'hello' is count as 1, 'Hello' is another 1.

Comment: - Although there is 2 world2017 in the string, but it not counted as 2 but separate world2017, think it because \b is word boundary.
- word with punctuation like project! are ignore, not match/counted

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand you correctly, but adding the modifier `i` (case-insensitive) to your regex should solve the case problem: => `"/\b".$word."\b/i". If you then change `preg_replace()` to `preg_replace_all()`, it should match all the possible occurences.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
preg_replace_all() page doesn't load.
/i just change to lower case, but it does not match and count as 2. 'Hello', 'hello'

Comment: @techi2 I will supply you with a solid answer if you will edit your question to provide 3 separate possible input strings, and display your expected output for each input string.  Please vary your input strings in such a way that it clarifies how to handle the fringe cases.  Please also post your php coding attempt in your question.  I will help you to find a clean solution.

Comment: ...most importantly, I need to know what you mean by "word with punctuation are ignored"  Do you mean apostrophe?  comma? hyphenated?

Comment: Let me ask differently/directly... if the string is `I'm going to rock your world. Not just your world, but your world's worlds and those worlds' worlds as well as each sub-world of every worlds' world ad nauseam.  So by World I mean WORLD and possibly "WORLD".` and the search word is `world` then what count would you expect to output, based on which substrings, and why?